# check all / uncheck all checkboxes using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, attr

So what I wanted to do was create a master checkbox that would select all and uncheck all as well. I found this jquery snipt that worked better than what I had created.

```
$("#checkboxSort").live( 'change', function() {
  $(".apply-single").attr( 'checked', $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ? 'checked' : '' );
});
```

The question I have is what exactly is this section saying:

```
$( this ).is( ':checked' ) ? 'checked' : ''
```

I understand that "this" is the ".apply-single" and that it is verify if it is "checked" but what does the rest of the section mean... in english? I have my thoughts on what it means but I much rather hear what someone knows rather than me guess.

Thanks for whomever can help.

Answer (score 2):

That's called a *ternary operator*.  The general format is

```
[boolean expression] ? [expression A] : [expression B]
```

It evaluates to expression A if the boolean expression evaluates to `true`, and to expression B if the boolean expression evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that "this" is the ".apply-single"

Nope. `this` actually refers to the `#checkboxSort` element.

`?` is the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Conditional_Operator) in JavaScript.

The particular bit of code you're asking about means (pseudocode):

```
if the element with ID "checkboxSort" is checked:
    check all elements with class "apply-single"
else:
    uncheck all elements with class "apply-single"
```

In short, the whole code snippet does this:

> Listen for changes on the element with id `checkboxSort`.
>   When such a `change` event fires, set the `checked` state of all elements with class `apply-single` to the new `checked` state of the `#checkboxSort` element.

---

Shameless self-promotion: I made a wee little jQuery plugin to handle this nicely. [Check it out](https://github.com/mjball/jQuery-CheckAll).

Comment: @patrick: yup. It is **the** conditional operator; it is **a** ternary operator (albeit the only ternary operator in JS).

Answer (score 1):

`this` is actually the `#checkboxSort` context **not** the `.apply-single`. So it is setting all `.apply-single` to the checked attribute of `#checkboxSort`.

It is a [**ternary operator**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). Similar to an `if` statement, simply inline.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shortform for

```
if($(".apply-single").is(':checked')) {
    $(".apply-single").attr("checked", "checked");
} else {
     $(".apply-single").attr("checked", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is using a ternary operator that works like this:

```
  <condition>?<consequent>:<alternative>
```

So `$( this ).is( ':checked'` is your condition that returns true or false depending on if the checkbox is checked or not. If true, then the 'checked' becomes the attribute otherwise the '' becomes the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In English, the code you're asking about says, if this item is checked, then set the "checked" attribute of all HTML elements having a CSS class of "apply-single" to "checked" -- if not, then set it to an empty value.

But please, confirm that the actual result doesn't result in attributes where checked="".

For checkboxes, the unchecked state isn't expressed by checked="", rather it is expressed by having no checked attribute at all.

Answer (score 0):

**.live() is deprecated. Use .on() instead.**

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/loginet/Rdc5r/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#checkboxSort").on('click', function () {
        $(".apply-single").prop("checked", $("#checkboxSort").prop("checked"));
    });

    $('.apply-single').on('click', function () {
        var total = $('input:not(#checkboxSort)').length;
        var checked = $('input:not(#checkboxSort):checked').length;         
        if (total == checked) {
            $('#checkboxSort').prop('checked', true);
        } else if (total > checked || checked == 0) {
            $('#checkboxSort').prop('checked', false);
        } 
    });    
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSort" />Check/Uncheck All</p>
<hr/>
<p id="p">
    <input type="checkbox" class="apply-single" />Checkbox 1
    <input type="checkbox" class="apply-single" />Checkbox 2
    <input type="checkbox" class="apply-single" />Checkbox 3
</p>
```